# How to get redirection to /Account/Login working with specific route configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a scenario where I have my routes all prefixed with a country code, e.g. http://www.example.com/US/Home - the country code is used to store country-specific information in session. This is all working fine except for unauthenticated requests (e.g. polling AJAX requests the fire after a session has expired, or a user leaves their browser open for long periods of time during and after deployments), at which point the system will try and redirect to `/Account/Login`, instead of the country specific URL, e.g. `/US/Account/Login`.  Because `/Account/Login` is not a valid route the system throws a `The controller for path '/Account/Login' could not be found or it does not implement IController.` exception.

First prize would be to able at to redirect to a country-specific e.g. `/US/Account/Login`, but that is not possible I could work with `/Account/Login`. If I add in a route for `/Account/Login` it gets superseded by the `DefaultCountryCode` route (if placed below in the route configuration), or it supersedes the `DefaultCountryCode` route (if placed below in the route configuration).

**Route Configuration**

```
// if placed here this supersedes DefaultCountryCode route
//routes.MapRoute("Account", "/Account/Login");

// e.g. http://www.example.com/US/Home
routes.MapRoute("DefaultCountryCode", "{countrycode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });

// if placed here this gets superseded by DefaultCountryCode route
//routes.MapRoute("Account", "/Account/Login");
```

Comment: What settings do you have in the Startup.Auth.cs file for your LoginPath?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom authorize attribute and add it to your controllers or register globally:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
      if (filterContext.Cancel && filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
      {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
          new RouteValueDictionary {
          { "controller", "Account" },
          { "action", "Login" },
          { "countrycode", /* extract it from: filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl or somewhere from context */ }
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) instead? You can create your controller and have two actions -

One that will be called when you have "US/Accounts/Login/{id}" and the other one can have the attribute for "Accounts/Login."